# when use editurl: 'clientArray' jqgrid see error dont found page

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

hi iam use   editurl: 'clientArray', in jqgrid but see  this error:
plase see pic error.how sloved this problem
[image: see pic error]
But when they edit, it should not call server.So i tried 'ClientArray' But still it shows Url is not set alert box
how sloved this problem

```
 myGrid.jqGrid({
                            pager: myPager, data: col[cols], datatype: 'local',
                            editurl: 'clientArray',
                            },
                            jsonReader: {
                                root: "Rows",
                                page: "Page",
                                total: "Total",
                                records: "Records",
                                repeatitems: true,
                                userdata: "UserData",
                                id: "Id",
                                cell: "RowCells"
                            },


                            cmTemplate: { editable: false, autoResizable: true },
                             loadonce: true,
                            shrinkToFit: true,

                            autoencode: true,

                        })
                        .navGrid( '#' + $(myPager)[0].id ,

                  { add: false, del: false, edit: false, search: false }   

                  )
                           .jqGrid('inlineNav', '#' + $(myPager)[0].id ,
                         {
                             // cloneToTop: true,
                             edit: false, add: true, save: false, cancel: false,
                             edittext: "ویرایش", addtext: "جدید", savetext: "ذخیره", canceltext: "لغو",

                             addParams: {
                                 position: "last",
                                 rowID: '0',
                                 useDefValues: true,
                                 addRowParams:  getInlineNavParams(true) 
                             },
                             //editParams: getInlineNavParams(false)
                         }

                         );

                        myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                            stringResult: true,//// وجود این سطر سبب می‌شود تا اپراتورها به سرور ارسال شوند
                            enableClear: false,
                            searchOnEnter: true,
                            searchOperators: true, // فعال سازی منوی اپراتورها
                            defaultSearch: "cn"

                        });
```

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? When you get the error: during adding of new row or during editing? You use `getInlineNavParams` function, which code you didn't post, to construct `addRowParams` option. In general, The usage `editurl: 'clientArray'` is correct. Could you prepare the demo (in jsfiddle, for example), which reproduce the problem?

Comment: im use @license jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid

Comment: What do `getInlineNavParams` function? If it would return `url` property, then `editurl: 'clientArray'` will be ignored. Could you prepare **the demo**, which reproduce the problem? By the way jqGrid 4.6 is 3.5 years old. I'd recommend you to try to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.15.1. You can try it by changing URLs, from which you load jqGrid to: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css`, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.1/i18n/min/grid.locale-fa.js`, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js`.

Comment: iam use jqGrid 4.15.1 dont show icon  edit save,..

Comment: iam use ver 4.15.1 is slove problem thnaks

Comment: You are welcome! I'd recommend you to read [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) too because you could reduce the code which you use and make it better readable if you'd migrate to free jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `editurl: 'clientArray'` is correct. I'd recommend you to try to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.15.1 - it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop after the main fork are made commercial and renamed to Guriddo jqGrid JS.

To test free jqGrid you can load jqGrid files directly from CDN:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.1/cs‌​s/ui.jqgrid.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.1/i1‌​8n/min/grid.locale-f‌​a.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.1/jq‌​uery.jqgrid.min.js
```

See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for more details.